# DialogFragment Blank and greyed out on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-dialogfragment

I've got a general main menu that pops up using a dialogfragment when an image is pressed. This worked with no problems on the Galaxy Tab S2 9.7 tablet when it was using 5.1 Lollipop. However, upon upgrading to 6.0.1 It no longer pops up. Instead, the menu looks like it wants to popup and the screen dims like the menu is there, but nothing appears on the screen. when I touch the screen, the screen brightens and returns me to the original main activity as if I clicked outside of the DialogFragment.

I've checked all my code and everything checks out from what I can see. I'm wondering if this may be a problem with the Dialog itself, rather than the calling Activity.

Here is the Code for the Calling Activity:

```
optionMenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.optionGear);
optionMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }

            DialogFragment editNameDialog = MainMenuDialog.newInstance("Set Event ID");
            //MainMenuDialog editNameDialog = MainMenuDialog.newInstance("Set Event ID");
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("ID", eventID);
            editNameDialog.setArguments(args);
            editNameDialog.show(ft, "dialog");

        }
    });
```

Here is a snippet of code from the Dialog:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container);



}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Here is the code for the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/options_menu"
android:layout_width="290dp" android:layout_height="460dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#7bffffff"
android:visibility="visible">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:enabled="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="EVENT INFORMATION"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="#ce2127" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_your_name" android:text="Event ID: (Must be in all caps)"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/event_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Re-Enter Event ID:"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/confirmEvent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textCapCharacters"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="CLEAR TEXT"
        android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:background="#a0a0a0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:background="#ce2127"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:background="#009634"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/uploadTitle"
    android:text="NON-UPLOADED VIDEOS"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="#ce2127"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="# VIDEOS TO UPLOAD:"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/videoCount"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CLICK TO UPLOAD VIDEOS"
    android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/uploadStatus"
    android:text="UPLOAD STATUS: IDLE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Application Version: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/verNumber"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've seen in the past where there are weird glitches on these Samsung devices due to the Touchwiz overlay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping didn't work for me, but I finally fixed it with adding         requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE):

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialog.window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Android 6.0.1 has a problem with XML layouts starting with the Linear layout that I chose.

I ended up wrapping the Linear Layout in a standard FrameLayout and BAM, everything showed up!

Interesting....

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/options_menu"
android:layout_width="290dp" android:layout_height="460dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#7bffffff">>
```